# Are some weight gradients equal?

Tags: machine-learning, python, backpropagation, derivation

I want to create a 3 layers neural network from scratch to perform linear regression.
The first and the second layer have 2 neurons, and the last layer has one neuron.

Feature vector x is divided into $x_{1}, x_{2}$
where $x_{1} = ax, x_2 = (1-a)x, 0 < a < 1$

Hence, there are 6 weights:
$w_{111}, w_{121}, w_{211}, w_{221}, w_{112}, w_{212}$.

To note that I'm not including biases since they aren't the object of the question and the activation function is linear, so I'm not including that as well.

Reading [the answer to this question](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/117281/does-derivative-of-an-activation-function-refer-to-process-of-back-propogation-i), I'm computing the gradient of each weight in this way: ($w_{111}$ and $w_{121}$ are took as examples)

$\frac{∂C}{w_{111}} = \frac{1}{m} \sum_{i=1}^m \frac{∂L_{i}}{w_{111}}$,
$\frac{∂L_{i}}{w_{111}} = (y-y')\frac{∂y'}{∂w_{111}}$,
$\frac{∂y'}{∂w_{111}} = \frac{∂z_{a1}}{∂w_{111}}$,
$\frac{∂z_{a1}}{∂w_{111}} = \frac{∂}{∂w_{111}}(w_{111}x_{1} + w_{121}x_{2}) = x_{1}$

$\frac{∂C}{w_{111}} = \frac{1}{m} \sum_{i=1}^m (y-y')x_{i1}$ 
$\frac{∂C}{w_{112}} = \frac{1}{m} \sum_{i=1}^m (y-y')x_{i2}$

But, since $z_{a1} = w_{111}x_{1} + w_{121}x_{2}$, and $z_{a2} = w_{211}x_{1} + w_{221}x_{2}$,

isn't $\frac{∂C}{w_{111}} = \frac{1}{m} \sum_{i=1}^m (y-y')x_{i1} = \frac{∂C}{w_{211}}$, and so, isn't $w_{111} = w_{211}$, and $w_{121} = w_{221}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that $\frac{∂y'}{∂w_{111}} \neq \frac{∂z_{a1}}{∂w_{111}}$, but $\frac{∂y'}{∂w_{111}} = \frac{∂z_{b}}{∂w_{111}}$, where $z_b$ is the sum of the products of all the z-vectors of the last layer with the weights.

So, here is an example of a NN with 3 layers, where the first two have 2 neurons and the last one has one neuron:

(with no activation function, layer n.1 z-vectors are just $x_i$)

- layer n. 2

$z_{11} = w_{111}x_1 + w_{112}x_2$
$z_{12} = w_{121}x_1 + w_{122}x_2$

- layer n. 3

$z_{21} = z_b = w_{211}z_{11} + w_{212}z_{12} $, hence:

$z_{21} = w_{211}(w_{111}x_1 + w_{112}x_2) + w_{212}(w_{121}x_1 + w_{122}x_2)$

Now, let's compute the derivatives:

- weights of layer n. 2

$\frac{∂z_b}{∂w_{111}} = x_1w_{211}$
$\frac{∂z_b}{∂w_{121}} = x_1w_{212}$
$\frac{∂z_b}{∂w_{112}} = x_2w_{211}$
$\frac{∂z_b}{∂w_{122}} = x_2w_{212}$

- weights of layer n. 3

$\frac{∂z_b}{∂w_{211}} = z_{11}$
$\frac{∂z_b}{∂w_{212}} = z_{12}$

As you can see, there is no weight derivative equal to another one.

I hope this can be useful to anyone interested in studying backpropagation.